# Caffe C++ set data in input layer

Tags: c++, qt, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

For one of my project, I took interest in Caffe, and more generaly in deep learning. After several hours, I managed to get Caffe installed on my computer. I am now trying to make us of it.

So I have already loaded the network as follow :

```
std::string model_file = "/home/CXX/Desktop/caffemodel/deploy.prototxt";
std::string trained_file = "/home/CXX/Desktop/caffemodel/modelWeights.caffemodel";

Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::CPU);
boost::shared_ptr<Net<float>> net_;
net_.reset(new Net<float>(model_file, TEST));
net_->CopyTrainedLayersFrom(trained_file);
```

The loaded network and weights are not mine. Please find below the structure of the input and output layers:

```
name: "simple_conv-dense"
input: "data"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 250
input_dim: 250
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  bottom: "data"
  type: "Convolution"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
```

The input is a single 250*250 depth (values normalized between 0 and 1) "image". The pre-processing is already handled, and my data is stored in a Matrix (personnal library, pointers to std::vector elements), so that you can access it this way like a 2D array (data[i][j])

The output of the network is organized in this order: [NbBlob][NbClass][outHeight][outWidth], giving in my case [1][46][250][250]

I have already written the code to retrieve the output:

```
Blob<float>* output_layer = net_->output_blobs()[0];
const float* begin = output_layer->cpu_data();
for (int k = 0; k < 46; k++)
    for (int h = 0; h < 250; h++)
        for (int w = 0; w < 250; w++){
            currentprob =  *(begin + ((k * 250 + h) * 250 + w));
```

This code has been checked, by summing the pixel-wise 46 class predections, giving obviously 1 as a result for a single pixel.

My problem is that I do not know how to feed my data in the network. I first retrieve the input layer by this method:

```
Blob<float>* input_layer = net_->input_blobs()[0];
```

From the debugger, I do know that input_layer has an attribute named capacity_ which has the expected value (62 500, being 250*250).

So here is my question: **How can one feed his data into the input layer**? I have spend quite some time looking by myself, but I have no idea where to look anymore.

Please note that I am not using OpenCV, and that I have barely any background on Deep learning (Bachelor student).

Thank you for the time you might spend helping me. Any kind of help (documentation, pseudo-code, code, explanations) is very welcome.

PS: using namespace caffe;

EDIT: added more input layer info. Typos.

Comment: There is a Q&A [SO: Setting input layer in CAFFE with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38637053/7478597).

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for your answer. I saw this question before, and decided that it was not close enough to my case (I am not loading from usual image format, but from binaries). However i looked into it, and saw that MemoryDataLayer is the input layer I need from the available ones. I have updated the CNN input section, because I think I realized something (this is exactly the first lines of my prototxt). The owner left the first line general so that one could define the most fitting input layer for his case, right? 
Also, i cannot reach caffe::MemoryDataLayer, only caffe::MemoryDataParameter

Comment: I googled a little bit and stumbled over [`caffe::MemoryDataLayer`](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/memorydata.html). Furthermore, there is a [Caffe c++ helloworld example with MemoryData input](https://medium.com/@shiyan/caffe-c-helloworld-example-with-memorydata-input-20c692a82a22).

Comment: Once again, i saw this article, but a while ago, during the installation process. I'll look deep into it, and it might be enough for me that have a better understanding of what I should do. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Managed to make it work with `caffe::MemoryDataLayer` as well, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try directly push the data to the net:

```
Blob<float>* input_layer = net_->input_blobs()[0];
float* input_data = input_layer->mutable_cpu_data();  // get pointer to Blob's data storage
for ( int i=0; i < 250; i++ ) {
    for ( int j=0; j < 250; j++ ) {
        input_data[i*250 + j] = data[i][j];  // I hope I did not filp anything here...
    }
}
net_->forward();  // do forward pass
```

Depending on how your `data` is arranged, you might be able to replace the nested loop with a more elegant `memcpy`...

Comment: I tried exactly this approach first, but `Blob<float>* input_layer = net_->input_blobs()[0];` crashed the program, and i have no clue why. I am currently working on the `caffe::MemoryDataLayer` as suggested above. 
Regaring `std::memcpy`, thank you very much for the advise, it looks totally adapted to my data (adjacent in memory).

Comment: Ok i got it, i had to modify the prototxt model to have a proper input layer at the very top. Your method is working now. Tanks a lot.

Comment: @AntoineMerlet glad I could help

Comment: @AtenaNguyen need another nested loop